# apply downloaded CSS on windows 8 metroUI app

Tags: windows-8, winjs

I have to download  CSS file and apply style sheet to my app. I downloaded this file at the local folder and referenced it as

```
style.href = "ms-appdata:///local/css//custom.css";
```

and appended to head as

```
document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(style);
```

after document onready event.
Seems it has no effect (but I can see this element in the dom browser).

So is there any restriction for css source: app package, local folder? May be this impossible to reference downloaded CSS due to MS limitations? Or may be I'm doing something wrong?  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do keep in mind, however, that you can access the `document.styleSheets` collection and list, add, or remove CSS rules dynamically from JavaScript. You can access the individual rules themselves through the DOM using statements like `document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.color = "red"` or you if you've fetched yourself some custom CSS text (dynamically from your other CSS file online) you can add its styles to one of your active style sheets using something like `document.styleSheets[0].cssText = "{my CSS code}"`. Do be sure that you're manipulating the right style sheet by checking the `document.styleSheets[0].href`.

Comment: Sad but looks like this is the last resort as I can't save file to app folder and can't use css  directly from local folder. Tnx for that trick with cssText.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're out of luck trying to head down that path.

> Note that, for security reasons, you cannot navigate to 
>   HTML you have downloaded to this location and you cannot 
>   run any executable or potentially executable code, such 
>   as script or CSS.

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh781215

Also, this blog post seems possibly helpful: http://palermo4.com/post/How-to-Use-IFrames-in-WinRT-Apps.aspx